# Chrome Extension: content_scripts - matches - contains

Tags: google-chrome-extension, contains, content-script, contain

I looked at [match patterns documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns), but can't find a way to have `matches` to contain a text.

E.g. how to make it work only for links that contains `test/22`?

Tried:

```
"content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches": ["https://*/test/22*"]
    }
}
```

and many others, no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each section of the url match should be defined (scheme, host, path), you may use `*` for the parts that may contain any value:

```
"https://*/*test/22*"
         ^ ^
      host |
           path starts here
```

Comment: Worked. Thanks a lot!